# How to translate a negative lookbehind to an ES5 compatible expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I made a RegExp that functions correctly in my code, but it is only compatible with ES2018 because it uses negative lookbehinds. A library is consuming the RegExp function, so I can't change how the RegExp is used.

I've tried placing a non-capturing groups at the start to find "not" the characters, but it does not work the same when I test it.

```js
/((?<![\^+-])[0-9]+)/g
```

When running my test suite regexes like `/(?:[^^+-])([0-9]+)/g` fail the tests because they include the preceding character.

Comment: How exactly are you implementing the pattern - what are you doing with the match(es)? Can you post the Javascript code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance `/((?<![\^+-])[0-9]+)/g` is used to match the element or group counts in `[Cu(NH3)6]^+6_3(H2O)^+5_12`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I already checked the solutions given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression). [Here](https://github.com/teamtofu/mcul/blob/9150fb1b9dc5a2c28d26537b33dbf7c9c338521a/src/parsers/basic.js#L13) is the context for my code. I am feeding the code into another library, as stated, so unfortunately I cannot use the reversal method.

Comment: You should post all the relevant Javascript code in the question itself (like in first comment). If you can't alter how the regex is being used (and only full matches are extracted), then what you're looking for isn't possible. I'd look to change the `Token` function

Answer (score 0):

the negative lookbehind matches at the start, so:

```
/(?:[^^+-]|^)([0-9]+)/g
```

Comment: `'[Cu(NH3)6]^+6_3(H2O)^+5_12'.match(/(?:[^^+-]|^)([0-9]+)/g)` still captures the preceding characters.